# store the created file in a folder in every iteration,MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file, loops, wav

I m creating .wav file in every iteration of for loop and that .wav files are stored in the current directory where I am working on .Now I want to create a folder in current directory and each created file should get store in the created folder in each iteration...

```
for i=1:size(seg_data(:,1))
    w(i,:)=data(seg_data(i,1): seg_data(i,2));
    wavwrite(w(i,:),['file_',num2str(i)]);
end
```

Comment: Does fullfile(filepath,['file_',num2str(i)]) work?

Comment: Should all wav files go into the same folder or should each file get its own folder?

Comment: @Dave all wav file should go to the same folder

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`mkdir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mkdir.html) to create the new directory (once).
Then you should provide the relative path to the new folder to `wavwrite`

```
subFolderName = 'mySubFolder'; % for example
mkdir( subFolderName ); % if folder exists, a warning is issued
for ii=1:size( seg_data, 1 )
    % ... do your stuff here
    wavwrite( w(ii,:), fullfile( subFolderName, sprintf( 'file_%d', ii ) ) );
end
```

Note the use of `fullfile` to create path string - works for windows as well as linux paths.

PS,
It is best [not to use `i` as a variable name in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).